# AngularJS Components and ng-change

Tags: angularjs

Using AngularJS & Ui-router.
Problem scenario:

I have a set of fixed radio button on 10 over pages with
Daily, Weekly , Monthly and Yearly.

Toggling the radio button above will do a state.go which will set the state params to the value of the radio button selected (using ng-change, ng-model).

Current code which I duplicated on every page.
Now I would like to create an AngularJS Component for those radio buttons.

```
<div>
<label>
   Daily
    <input type="radio" ng-model="dateModel" value="Daily" name="radioDateType"
           ng-change="SetDateTypeOption(dateModel)">
    <span class="checkmark"></span>'
</label>
<label>
   WTD
    <input type="radio" value="WTD" ng-model="dateModel" name="radioDateType"
           ng-change="SetDateTypeOption(dateModel)">
    <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
</div>
```

This is a simplified plunker (Not working) but you can see what i'm trying to achieve. 
First - I'm unable to even get the radio button to show despite already using a template.
Second - If it's able to show, I want it to show an alert when I toggle between the radio buttons (This is a test that the ng-change is working)
Lastly - I'll need to implement $state.go on every ng-change.

https://plnkr.co/edit/N5CDz0ZBhSG1leq3Hiw2?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

The reason it's not loading is because you're not bootstrapping your app. Just add the `ng-app` directive to body. Everything else is correct.

See updated link: https://plnkr.co/edit/P34c6im4ojUI69sQDfhh?p=preview